# Code migration install 1.9 to installData 2.0

Tags: module, magento2, migration

I have started learning 1.9 two months ago but i have decided to start learning magento 2 instead because i heard that it is totally different world.

I have followed an Inchoo tutorial how to create a custom entity in 1.9 for blog (i done the same just for slider) but i have started to do it partly in magento 2 way. Module is successfully detected but it reports that i need to upgrade my database with command XY. After running command i get

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.
```

Now i know that old install script does not work with magento 2.0, as far as i am noob to these official non step-by-step documentations i am searching for help here.

Actual install script looks like script for 1.9 magento

https://github.com/erikkubica/Limeslide/blob/master/Setup/InstallData.php

Can someone help me to migrate code and explain everything that i need to change?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`There are no commands defined` message hides some internal error: usually an error in `composer.json` or `module.xml` file:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2300

Comment: thank you, there was error in xml now it starts to upgrade, actually its giving error to install script "[ErrorException] Undefined variable: this" also i found out that controllers also had huge changes so i am rewriting them to mage2 way, now i am just thinking if there is any change in custom eav entity