# Magento2 cannot run setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, module

I ran into this while building a custom module

```
Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
```

When running this command I got another issue:

```
There are no commands defined in the setup namespace
```

Is this a know issue or did I something wrong?
Thanks

*****EDIT****

app/code/Unreal/Custom/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Unreal_Custom" schema_version="2.0.0" setup_version="0.0.2">
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/Unreal/Custom/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Unreal_Custom',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: You should set permission 777 for var and pub folder again

Comment: this does not fix it , sorry

Comment: Can you add the folder/file structure for your module, assuming that `setup:upgrade` work when your module is removed then the issue lies within your module

Comment: Have you installed Magento 2 already?

Comment: are you able to upload your `module.xml` and do you have a `registration.php` ?

Comment: @rob3000 just uploaded :)

Comment: `schema_version` is no longer used, please use just `setup_version`. Also, we no longer hardcode the path to the schema, URNs are used. Please see example here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/AdminNotification/etc/module.xml#L8 Also, can you run the upgrade command again with -vvv flag. It should show stack trace if you are in developer mode.

Comment: @ChristophHa if you get the answer plz post it

Comment: @ND17 I just did it i vendor folder instead of app an it worked there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`There are no commands defined` is a generic message which hides a real problem. Usially the real problem is an error in a `module.xml` file or a `composer.json` file:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2300
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/91097

Answer (score 0):

You have this error, because magento can't initialize all commands. Error in your custom module. Try temporary remove it.

Comment: but I want to add a custom module :)
So what to do in this case?

Comment: I think issue with xml files. You should validate files etc/confix.xml di.xml module.xml etc

Comment: just updated the xml in this question

Answer (score 0):

i hope you dint set php in env variable,

- open cmd
- cd xampp/php
- php prject_fullPath\Project_folder\bin\magento setup:upgrade

this in my localhost , if your in server go to php folder and run the command with full path

Comment: this returns the error message There are no commands defined in the setup namespace

Answer (score 0):

i hope hen issue is in composer.json or module.xml 
below are the 3 imp file make sure all correct

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sugarcode_Test" setup_version="2.0.6" schema_version="2.0.6">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "sugarcode/module-test",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Sugarcode\\Test\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

and app\code\Sugarcode\Test\registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sugarcode_Test',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: Please remove `schema_version`. It is no longer used. Also, schemas are now specified via URNs

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and figure out the issue. I am posting this, hoping it may help others.
Actually in my case the problem was the php system environment variable was not set.
Go to system environment variable add your php location to path, in my case `";D:\xampp\php".`
Or go to your terminal and go to `bin` folder inside magento root directory and run the script mentioned above.